# PHP, no puedo insertar la ruta de una imagen en la base de datos

Tags: php, html, sql

Tengo que insertar imagenes en una base de datos, y estoy usando el codigo siguiente para aquello, la idea es que reciba la ruta de la imagen y la ponga en la base de datos (junto con mover dicha imagen a una nueva carpeta llamada fotos). El problema es que, aunque el codigo no se caiga, no guarda la ruta completa, es decir, no recibe la variable $imagen.

Y tampoco mueve la imagen de su carpeta vieja a la actual.

¿Alguien sabe si lo que intento es imposible o tengo mal escrito el codigo?

```php
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $id_est = $_REQUEST["id_est"];

    $nombre_est = $_REQUEST["nombre_est"];

    $imagen = $_FILES["imagen"]["name"];

    $ruta = $_FILES["imagen"]["tmp_name"];

    $destino = "fotos/".$imagen;

    copy($ruta,$destino);

    if(!empty($id_est)){
        $dbhost = "localhost";
        $dbusername = "root";
        $dbpassword = "";
        $dbname = "test";

        //Aqui se crea la conexion

        $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost ,$dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);

        if(mysqli_connect_error()){
            die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        else{
            if(!empty($nombre_est)){
                // Attempt insert query execution

                $sql = "INSERT INTO estudiante VALUES ('$id_est', '$nombre_est', '$destino')";

                if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
                    echo "Estudiante ingresado";
                } else{
                    echo "ERROR ". mysqli_error($conn);
                }
            }
        }

        $conn->close();
    }
    else{
        echo "Por favor, ponga un id";
        die;
    }
?>
```

Por si las moscas, añado tambien el codigo de mi formulario:

```html
<form method="post" action="../api/imagen.php">
          <fieldset data-role="collapsible">
            <legend>Ingresar un Alumno</legend>
              <label for="name">Id:</label>
              <input type="text" name="id_est">
              <label for="name">Nombre:</label>
              <input type="text" name="nombre_est">
              <label for="img">Foto Alumno:</label>
              <input type="file" name="imagen" id="imagen">  
          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Te está faltando el [enctype](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/form#attr-enctype) en el formulario:

```
<form method="post" action="../api/image.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

> multipart/form-data: Usar este valor si se está usando el elemento `<input>` con el atributo `type` ajustado a "file".

Comment: Hola! muchas gracias, lo hice y resulto, pero ahora tira otro error, me dice que los indices se encuentran vacios, ¿tiene que ver con que estan en otro archivo php?

Comment: @Hugo el código PHP que pusiste no corresponde al archivo `image.php`? Si es así, por favor pone el contenido de dicho archivo que es donde se está enviando el formulario.